# Intercept SIP outgoing packets and alter them enroute

Tags: .net, sockets

I have a SIP server that I don't control the code for and I'd like to intercept the outgoing SIP invites   (with code running on the SIP Server which is running Windows) and rewrite the display part of the FROM field in the SIP INVITE.

Is this possible in Windows?  With .Net?  Which library do I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Could routing it to a proxy server of your choice be an option or you want to do it specifically on the platform?

1. On the same platform what you are looking for is a Network level SIP / Text parsing tool, that grabs the packet before it reaches the network layer and is forwarded to the destination. I haven't come across any that has the ability to do that unless the SIP server itself allowed access which it doesn't. DPI tools do it to some degree but the ability to switch and change SIP or Text in a UDP packet is something i encountered.
2. Routing it to a different destination like "pit-stop". Where you can tweak and change every single things and then send it back on its way.  Proxy Servers or B2BUA based SBC can also help you tweak and change these headers. Industry wide its usually referred to as message transformation rules and there are different ways of doing it. Static as well as Dynamic as needed.